# Clarinet Ligature on Alto Sax?

Tags: saxophone, clarinet, mouthpieces

I bought a semi expensive ligature for my clarinet, and I would like to know if it is a good idea to use it on an Alto Sax. I've tried using a cheap one on my alto sax, and it seemed to work alright (they're not that different in size). I hope I can use my good ligature on my alto sax because it makes quite a difference on my clarinet. Is this in any way bad for the instruments? If it isn't, is it worth it getting an Alto Sax ligature?

Comment: If the ligature fits it should be ok for the instrument.

Comment: Are you asking about metal ligatures or leather/synthetic ones?

Comment: @tim Leather/synthetic. Although the cheap one I tried was metal.

Answer (score 2):

I am surprised that the clarinet ligature fits on the alto saxophone mouthpiece (I play both.) What do you mean by "fit"? The ligature should fit snugly on the mouthpiece under the "u" part of the reed. It should secure the reed just where the reed and mouthpiece naturally meet. If the ligature is too high, the reed will not vibrate properly.

Comment: It is well beneath the u and the line.

Comment: @Erik, then it should be fine.

Comment: Is it in amy way damaging to the ligature?

Comment: @Erik, if it is tightening properly, I don't think so. However, I have heard that the leather ligatures do change over time. (I never had one long enough to notice.) I currently have a Vandoren metal ligature with the interchangeable plates, which I love.